# Socket.io connection to server

Tags: node.js, sockets

I cant seem to get the socket to connect to the server, im not getting any errors but the socket does not seem to be making a connection with the server

```
var request=require("request");
var server;



request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/designrooms'}, function (err,response, body) {
    var designroomID = JSON.parse(body)[0]._id;
    console.log(designroomID);
    server = request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/designrooms' + designroomID})
});

var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("connected");
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Try paste this into developer console (press enter) and see debug result.

`localStorage.debug = '*';`

Comment: In the node.js is the best package for sockets WS - https://github.com/websockets/ws

Answer (score 0):

javascript and node are asynchronous.

In your case, this line

`var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);`

is executed before this line :

```
`server = request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/designrooms' + designroomID})`
```

due to your request callback. So, your server isn't initialized.

Try to move your listener inside the request callback.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want. I can't actually understand your objective with your first request. (edit your question). By the way, you have to make your server listening a port (3000 in your case). `server.listen(3000);`